# Get XML from Asset NullPointerException

Tags: android, xml

I am working off of [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) example in which the author pulls+parses an xml file via HTTP request. I am attempting to manipulate this project to instead load the same xml from the assets folder. When I load it however I am getting a Null Pointer. I am passing context as I believe I should in addition to loading the "url" from the assets folder. Where is my error in this code?

MainActivity snippet-initializing url string and calling getXML

```
static final String URL = "file:///android_asset/sample.xml";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ...
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL, context); // getting XML
    ...
}
```

XMLParser Class' method:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String URL, Context context){
    String xml = null;
    AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream is = am.open(URL); //This is line 40
        int length = is.available();
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        is.read(data);
        xml = new String(data);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return xml;
}
```

EDIT: Added Logcat

```
09-19 13:41:43.442: W/dalvikvm(4841): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.xmlparsing/com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.XMLParser.getXmlFromUrl(XMLParser.java:40)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java:42)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-19 13:41:43.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4841):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: please post the LogCat showing the NullpointerException and Stacktrace

Comment: @Ridcully right, slipped my mind. Updated.

Comment: Can you step through the code and find out where the NullPointerException is happening?

Comment: @CaseyB My thought is that String URL is returning null for some reason, when I switch the variable URL to be an actual HTTP request (and turn on the HTTP request method in the sample I linked to) everything runs fine. The error is in either the method or the String. I'm not sure why URL would be null though as it's loaded in the assets folder as 'sample.xml'

Comment: You think the URL is null or you know the URL is null?  Set a breakpoint and debug the app to be sure.

Comment: See my edits..I noticed the whole log wasn't up. It looks like line 40 is the NullPointer which is first use of the URL String. I'll check debug mode..

Comment: Correction it's the asset manager causing the exception. I can't find any similar cases on SO, any ideas?

Comment: have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Where have you defined a value to `context` variable at line `String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL, context); // getting XML`?

From What I see your parameter is *null*. Inside `getXmlFromUrl()` method you don't need to provide a `Context` as a parameter since you are inside an `Activity`. Just call `getAssets()` method without the `context` variable before.